# Почему MongoDB не сохраняет данные?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript

Почему при работе с mongodb через node js когда делаю post запросы данные сохраняются а после полной перезагрузки компьютера кроме одного файла в коллекции ничего нет а было 10 !